# serial data matlab and arduino not send data from mega to uno via simulink

Tags: matlab, serial-port, simulink, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I send data from matlab command via serial to arduino uno in
this command :
arduino=serialport("COM9",115200);
writeline(arduino,"45,90,135,180,225,273,231");

I want to send this data from serial arduino mega serial1 to serial0 of arduino uno via simulink i tryed this but it not work

I tryed this and it did not work:
[image: thats what i tryed]

I tryed to send data via 0 port - also did not work

Comment: "It not work" is neither English nor a sufficient problem description.